# Data upload from custom iOS keyboard

Tags: ios, xcode, ios-keyboard-extension

Is it possible to upload data from custom keyboard to the web service? I mean that an app works on custom keyboard and using it for operations belong to web service like registering user to a website or logging in etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, but the user must manually switch on "Allow Full Access" in iOS's Settings app (in the same place where the keyboard is installed in the first place). Your keyboard extension must also request open access by setting the `RequestsOpenAccess` key to true under `NSExtensionAttributes` in your extension's info plist.

See more about this option under "Designing for User Trust" on Apple's keyboard extension webpage: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/ExtensibilityPG/Keyboard.html